# HashSet.contains does not behave as expected with hashCode and equals

Tags: java, hashset

I have a class called MyClass:

```
public class MyClass extends abstractClass implements
        someInterface {

    Set<VNode> relation_;
    Set<VNode> x_;
    Set<VNode> y_;


     @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (!super.equals(obj)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof MyClass)) {
            return false;
        }
        MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;

        if (relation_ == null) {
            if (other.relation_ != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!relation_.equals(other.relation_)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (x_ == null) {
            if (other.x_ != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!x_.equals(other.x_)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (y_ == null) {
            if (other.y_ != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!y_.equals(other.y_)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int res = new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37).append(relation_).append(x_)
                .append(y_).append(getWeight()).toHashCode();

        return res;
    }
}
```

The abstract class is as follows:

```
public abstract class abstractClass {

    double weight_;


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof abstractClass)) {
            return false;
        }
        abstractClass other = (abstractClass) obj;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(weight_) != Double
                .doubleToLongBits(other.weight_)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight_;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(weight_);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

}
```

Now, if I have `HashSet<MyClass> s1` and an `MyClass i1`, even if `s1` has an element `s1i` whith `s1i.equals(i1)=true` and `s1i.hashCode()=i1.hashCode()`, `s1.contains(i1)` gives me `false`.

Any explanations?

Other classes:

```
public class VNode {

    Mention mention_;


    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof VNode)) {
            return false;
        }
        VNode other = (VNode) obj;
        if (mention_ == null) {
            if (other.mention_ != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!mention_.equals(other.mention_)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((mention_ == null) ? 0 : mention_.hashCode());
        return result;
    }



}




public class Mention extends Range {


    private final int                           id_;


    public Mention(final int start, final int end) {
        super(start, end);

        id_ = getNextMentionID();
    }

}





public class Range {


    private final int start_;

    private final int end_;

    /**
     * Contr.
     * 
     * @param start
     * @param end
     */
    public Range(final int start, final int end) {
        start_ = start;
        end_ = end;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Range)) {
            return false;
        }
        Range other = (Range) obj;
        if (end_ != other.end_) {
            return false;
        }
        if (start_ != other.start_) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + end_;
        result = prime * result + start_;
        return result;
    }



}
```

Comment: Please post the `hashCode()` method of the VNode class.

Comment: So two mentions are equal if the range is equal? The id does not matter?

Comment: Yes, the ID is not taken into consideration for equality.

Comment: Ah ok. I think the hashcode of sets depends on their element order, which is not defined for a hashset. Does it work when you use TreeSets instead?

Comment: But I do check the hashCodes, which are equal. Also, equal objects have equal hashCodes

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Have you tried to debug the contains() call?

Answer (score 2):

Your equals() method is not readable at all. Since you are using HashCodeBuilder in hashCode(), why not use EqualsBuilder as well?

Version a)

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(obj == null || obj.getClass()!=getClass()){
        return false;
    }
    MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
    return new EqualsBuilder()
      // check parent properties first
      .append(this.getWeight(), other.getWeight())
      .append(this.relation_, other.relation_)
      .append(this.x_, other.x_)
      .append(this.y_, other.y_)
      .isEquals();
}
```

Version b)

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    // delegate to parent equals first
    if(!super.equals(obj)){
        return false;
    }
    MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
    return new EqualsBuilder()
      .append(this.relation_, other.relation_)
      .append(this.x_, other.x_)
      .append(this.y_, other.y_)
      .isEquals();
}
```

Comment: You forgot the super call to equals. And `getClass()` calls introduce problems as well - at least it introduces unnecessary limitations for some cases.

Comment: @Voo no, using `getClass()` instead of `instanceof` is a feature, not a bug. It makes sure I am dealing with the same type, not a subtype. Otherwise you have an asymmetric equals().

Comment: But I added getWeight() to the equals check, so that the relevant properties of the parent class are also checked. In fact I added a second version to do it in two different flavors

Comment: You can implement a correct version while still using instanceof, it just needs a helper method - I didn't say it's a bug, I said it introduces unnecessary limits, which is true (I can't extend your class and still expect it to work even if I don't introduce new attributes, say because I just want to log something). But the real problem is not calling `super.equals()` imo - that makes it basically impossible to guarantee a correct implementation if the base class implementation should ever change.

Answer (score 1):

Each class should only be concerned with its own variables when calculating equals and hashcode. So, in your MyClass instead of calling `getWeight()` you should be using the hashcode of the super class. Like you are with `equals()`!. In this case the effect will be the same.

```
public int hashCode() {
    int res = new HashCodeBuilder(super.hashcode(), 37).append(relation_).append(x_)
            .append(y_);

    return res;
}
```

This means any changes to the base class that may affect equals and hashcode are confined to the class and you don't have to update the sub classes.

(Not really an answer, more an observation but its too big for a comment)

Comment: If apache commons-lang are used ObjectUtils.hashCodeMulti(Object..) is faster and does not create new objects on each hashCode() call.